# Is there a way to match 2 specific field values in a sub-document array in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I have data in the following format:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f281caf3494701c38711e96"), 
    "WidgetId" : "0233261", 
    "Specs" : [
        {
            "WidgetType" : "A",
            "AmountLow" : NumberLong(0), 
            "AmountHigh" : NumberLong(0), 
        }, 
        {
            "WidgetType: "A",
            "AmountLow" : NumberLong(0), 
            "AmountHigh" : NumberLong(500), 
        }, 
        {
            "WidgetType" : "A"
            "AmountLow" : NumberLong(1), 
            "AmountHigh" : NumberLong(1000), 
        }
    ]
}
```

The data however is wrong in that I can't have a value of `"Specs.AmountLow" = 0` and `"Specs.AmountHigh" > 0`, they should either be 0/0 or >0/>0.

I am having no luck finding the documents which have a specific combination of `"Specs.AmountLow" = 0` and `"Specs.AmountHigh" > 0`. Here are two queries I've attempted without success:

Attempt 1:

```
db.widgets.find(
    { 
        "Specs.AmountLow" : NumberLong(0), 
        "Specs.AmountHigh" : { 
            "$gt" : NumberLong(0)
        }
    }, 
    { 
        "WidgetId" : 1.0, 
        "Specs.AmountLow" : 1.0, 
        "Specs.AmountHigh" : 1.0
    }
)
```

The above query send back all results as long as the `AmountLow` is 0 or the `AmountHigh` is greater than 0, so in the example data, all of the array values are matched, even if there's no 0/>0 value

I tried this one next:

```
db.widgets.find(
    { 
        "$and" : [
            { 
                "Specs.$.AmountLow" : NumberLong(0)
            }, 
            { 
                "Specs.$.AmountHigh" : { 
                    "$gt" : NumberLong(0)
                }
            }
        ]
    }, 
    { 
        "WidgetId" : 1.0, 
        "Specs.AmountLow" : 1.0,
        "Specs.AmountHigh" : 1.0
    }
);
```

This one however didn't return any results, even when I had data confirmed with a 0/>0 value

How to I write a query that finds the specific sub-document combination of `AmountLow = 0` and `AmountHigh > 0` and, as a corollary, how do I update ONLY those records to have `AmountLow = 1`?

Expected result:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f281caf3494701c38711e96"), 
    "WidgetId" : "0233261", 
    "Specs" : [
        {
            "WidgetType: "A",
            "AmountLow" : NumberLong(0), 
            "AmountHigh" : NumberLong(500), 
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try,

When you use [$-positional](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#array-field-limitations) this will return only one matching document from array and in array

- use `$elemMatch` for array element matching
- use `$` positional after array field name in projection,

```
db.widgets.find({
  Specs: {
    $elemMatch: {
      AmountLow: 0,
      AmountHigh: {
        $gt: 0
      }
    }
  }
},
{
  _id: 1,
  WidgetId: 1,
  "Specs.$": 1
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/g56N3tPT387)

---

Instead of above example you can use [aggregate()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/index.html), this example will return all matching documents from array,

- [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) to get filtered documents from array on the base of conditions

```
db.widgets.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      Specs: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$Specs",
          cond: {
            $and: [
              { $eq: ["$$this.AmountLow", 0] },
              { $gt: ["$$this.AmountHigh", 0] }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HU-gQAvOs0e)